# How to bind a Kendo treeview to a file directory

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I would like to display a folder hierarchy as a Kendo treeview.  I assume this involves converting the directory into JSON.

Is this possible and the right way to accomplish my goal or is there another way to bind the treeview to a remote file directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your tags are `kendo-ui` and `C#` I assume you are using `Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC`. If not just change the view code with appropriate JS and the other code should work as expected in ASP.NET MVC.

Create controller `PathController` with 2 actions: `Read` and `Index`.

In your `Index` **view** call Kendo UI tree view helpers

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("PathTreeView")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Path"))
    )
)
```

Create a **view model** `KendoTreeViewViewModel` for the kendo tree view:

```
public class KendoTreeViewViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
}
```

In your `Read` **action** return JSON with files and folders:

```
public JsonResult Read(string path)
{
    const string StartDirectory = @"C:\";
    path = path ?? StartDirectory;
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(file => 
        new KendoTreeViewViewModel
            {
                Id = file,
                HasChildren = false,
                Name = Path.GetFileName(file)
            });

    var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(dir =>
        new KendoTreeViewViewModel
            {
                Id = dir,
                HasChildren = true,
                Name = Path.GetFileName(dir)
            });

    var result = files.ToList();
    result.AddRange(directories);
    result = result.OrderBy(x => x.HasChildren).ToList();

    return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: This is working great with two minor adjustments.  

`read.Action("Path", "Read")` should be `read.Action("Read", "Path")` and `Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir))` was getting the name of the root directory so I changed it to `Path.GetFileName(dir)`